# momentfit::gmm4 model output interepretation

Tags: r, generalized-moments

I specify my GMM routine

```
gmm_out <- 
      gmm4(
        g = fn,
        x = mTs,
        theta0 = vTheta0,
        type = "iter",
        vcov = "HAC",
        method = "L-BFGS-B",
        # tet = (a1   ,   a2,   v1,   v2,       rho, eta,       H1,       H2,   mu1, mu2)
        # tet = (1    ,    2,    3,    4,         5,   6,        7,        8,     9,  10)
        lower = c(1e-2, 1e-2, 1e-2, 1e-2, 1e-3 - 1 , - 2,     2e-2,     2e-2,   - 2, -2),
        upper = c(   2,    2,    3,    3,  1 - 1e-3,   2, 1 - 1e-2, 1 - 1e-2,     2,  2)
      )
```

and get the following output. Can anybody explain me why `Convergence iteration: 0` despite the fact that the routine actually found the optimal parameters that I was looking for? Also the error `Convergence optim : 52` is not clear to me. The package `gmm4` lacks of documentation.

[image]